# Split document into pages with titles (Was: tricky Question In java )

Tags: java, sqlite, foreach

I've a little tricky problem 
i'm trying to save pages of document in sqlite ..the thing is i want in certain points lets say when it find the  font <font tag which is mark the titles of the chapters of the document .. so in short i want the the title of the chapter to be the begining of the page.. so i've did that code `

```
Integer i=0;
int j= 0;
StringBuilder page = new StringBuilder();
String [] paragraphs = content.split("\n");
for (String paragraph : paragraphs){
        i++;
           page.append(paragraph).append("\n");
        Integer length = paragraphs.length;
        String stringPage=page.toString();



        stringPage= stringPage.replaceAll("\n","<br/>");
        String[] pageContents  = stringPage.split(" ");
        boolean beginOfStory=false;
        for (String pageContent:pageContents){

            if(pageContent.contains("<font")){
                beginOfStory=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(pageContents.length >180 || beginOfStory){

               j++;
               prep.setLong(1, j);
               prep.setString(2, stringPage);
               prep.addBatch();
               page =new StringBuilder();

    }

}
```

of course i know that this make the title to be the last thing in the page and it begin the new page after it .. but i want the title to be in the new page.. it's tricky for me and i can't get a clue for it.. any help..hope i've describe it will

thanks in advance

Comment: are you miss south carolina ? so as such as :-)

Comment: Whats that prep object and what does the table look like? You should be able to get the title to the front by structuring the table so that it can be retrieved that way.

Comment: prep here is for prepare statement for sqlite i don't know how the table structure have to do anything in this case.. the table is so simple it's two column one called id and the other called page, to save the pages ..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your design you are doing this:

1. Splitting a string into paragraphs.
2. Building a page by adding paragraphs one at a time
3. **After** you add the paragraph to your page you check to see if there is a title by breaking up the entire **page** into words and looking for a word that contains the start of the HTML font tag.
4. A page is considered complete if you found a title or it has more than 180 words

So if you want to put titles at the top check the paragraph for a title first **before** you add it to your page.  Of course this also assumes that the way you detect titles is accurate in the first place (which I am less than certain of...)

Try this approach:

1. Split into paragraphs
2. Check the paragraph for a title marker
3. If title found store the current page and start another with title paragraph as the first paragraph
4. If title not found add paragraph and check page length
5. If page length boundary reached store page and start another empty page

That should work...